# How can I change the keyboard shortcut for Emoji picker?

Tags: shortcut-keys, emoji

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> are invoking the Emoji picker in Ubuntu Bionic (18.04). I use that shortcut in another application. How can I change the shortcut?

Comment: If someone is struggling with disabling Emoji shortcut in VS Code, here is a possible solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269241/229740

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125726/how-to-disable-ctrl-shift-e-keybinding-from-showing-eeeee-and-loading-emoji-opti/1269239#1269239

Answer (score 42):

On needs to run `ibus-setup` and in the "Emoji" tab

[image: IBus Preferences dialog box showing the Emoji tab]

....change the shortcut (click on the three dots that are focused in the screenshot). I had to restart my computer after that so that the change would take effect (not sure how to restart IBUS).

Comment: I'm not able to run it it raises an error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
                                                                                                │  File "/usr/share/ibus/setup/main.py", line 33, in <module>
                                                                                                │    from gi import require_version as gi_require_version
                                                                                                │ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Comment: I would try installing `sudo apt install python3-gi`

Comment: I did try that, nothing is installing because it already is installed.

Comment: Sounds weird, did you try force reinstalling it?

Comment: Appart from that, I would try looking if the files that are supposed to be installed are where they are supposed to be - or try also installing `python-gi` for Python 2?

Comment: the who operating system has been acting up lately, I think I'm gonna reinstall it completely. ( thanks for the help).

Comment: Im on 18.04 and cant seem to get this key combo to work. Ive tried using `ibus-setup` to change it to other combos, with no luck. The default `ctrl shift e` combo does nothing. All of my other key combos work. I am also testing this in native apps like Gedit, Geary, and TODO. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sudo ibus-setup`

Comment: `sudo ibus-setup` works, but the defined keyboard shortcut doesn’t.

Comment: I have to do this every time I install a new ubuntu install. I use this keyboard shortcut a lot and it just messes any input field I happen to have focused.
Thank you very much for this response.

Comment: Thank you so much bro, Its now perfectly working for me.

Answer (score 9):

To change on the command line in Ubuntu 19.04, you can use `gsettings`. For example, to remove the shortcut, you can do:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "@as []"
```

To re-enable to the default shortcut:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey "['<Control><Shift>e']"
```

To change to a different shortcut, run the command just above but change the part `<Control><Shift>e` to the desired combination.

Comment: Worked for me on KDE. Nothing else worked: ibus-setup, setting the GTK_IM_MODULE env var for VS Code (the app i had problems with)

Comment: If you have installed VS Code on Ubuntu using Snap, here is a solution for disabling Emoji shortcut: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269241/229740

Comment: Damn, this other hack still doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and VSCode 1.53...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug listed here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1885914

The solution that I found is to remove the `ibus` package:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus
sudo apt-get purge ibus
```

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan and reinstall `ibus`:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus
```

Go to language support and set the iBus method, for user and root

In the terminal for user and root:

```
ibus-setup
```

and change the shortcuts in the emoji tab

In the terminal for user and root:

```
im-config
```

and set ibus

For user in the terminal:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Include the following lines at the end:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```