# How to disable ctrl-shift-e keybinding from showing eEEEE and loading Emoji options

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I type the keybinding sequence <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + e</kbd> I'm getting eEEEE. This allows me to specify an emoji, but I need <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + e</kbd> for use in VIM.

How can I disable this keybinding. I've already tried running `ibus-setup` to remove the emoji launcher, but I still get the eEEEE.

[image: This is what happens in xed when I type "ctrl-shift-e"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable emoji input in Ubuntu Mate 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046418/how-do-i-disable-emoji-input-in-ubuntu-mate-18-04)

Comment: In PyCharm it ctrl-shift-e is [recent locations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#recent_locations)

Answer (score 47):

In terminal type `ibus-setup`, go to the Emoji tab, and delete/change the keybindings.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This fixed all my ctrl-shift shortcuts in Terminator. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't solve it for me on Kubuntu, KDE Plasma, X11, VSCodium snap (it was still using the original key shortcuts even after remapping). The command-line answer worked.

Comment: I had to run `sudo ibus-setup`

Answer (score 20):

**For VS Code if installed via Ubuntu Snap** you need an [input method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/understanding-setting-up-different-input-methods/262220#262220) other than `ibus`.

If you run VS Code from command line do:

```
$ GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code
```

You can also add an alias for that in .bashrc: `alias code='GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code'`

To configure the Dash launcher (assuming VS Code is installed using Snap):

- The launcher file is located at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop` or `~/.local/share/applications/code_code.desktop`, or both
- Edit it and add `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` to `Exec` commands:

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
...

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
...
Exec=env GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --new-window %F
Icon=/snap/code/41/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
```

Comment: Looks like this question could be a dupe of the other one you answered (or vice versa)

Comment: Just filed a bug report for codium snap: https://github.com/snapcrafters/codium/issues/13

Comment: The file at `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop` was overwritten by the system and reverted back to deafaults. Copying to `~/.local/share/applications/code_code.desktop` and editing it there works more reliably in 22.04.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but for VS Code. The ibus solution didn't work for me. What worked is:

```
$ GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code
```

Make sure that you close all VS Code windows before running this.

However, I have tested this for `vim` and it didn't work there - not sure why. There is a nice explanation of the concepts [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/262220/43238) and a relevant VS Ccode bug (with mitigations) [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48480).

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04. You can add an alias in your .bashrc file: `alias code='GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" code'`.

Comment: I simply added `export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` to my `.profile` which fixed the problem in all apps

Comment: Ubuntu 21 this is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Like [kuceb answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138628/349837) but using CLI, changing to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + **Super** + e</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey $'[\'<Control><Super><Shift>e\']'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug listed here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1885914

The solution that I found is to remove the ibus package:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ibus
$ sudo apt-get purge ibus
```

Go to updates and set the repository for *focal fossa* version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent ***eoan***

Go to updates and set the repository for focal fossa version for Ubuntu and remove the remanescent eoan and reinstall ibus:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus
```

Go to language suport and set the iBus method, for user and root

In the terminal for user and root:

```
ibus-setup
```

and change the shortcuts in the emoji tab

In the terminal for user and root:

```
im-config
```

and set ibus

For user in the terminal:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Include the following lines at the end:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

Answer (score 1):

Open **Ibus preferences** in your launcher, visit the **Emoji tab**, then click the **...** beside Emoji Annotation to either **Delete** or change the shortcut:

[image]