# Ctrl-shift-e does not create vertical split on my Ubuntu 20.04 Machine

Tags: ibus

On my teminator, if I want to create a vertical split using ctrl-shift-e, I see an e with an underline, which I believe is emoji interception. **I have tried deleting emoji annotation in ibus-setup** (I had to launch using `sudo ibus-setup`), but the same thing still persists. Any ideas? [image: This is what my ibus-setup looks like]

Comment: Update: I managed to get the emoji annotation successfully disabled by `gsettings set org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji hotkey $'[\'<Control><Super><Shift>e\']'`, following this link : https://askubuntu.com/a/1428373/1646390
However, my ibus-setup gui still looks the same as above. I'm not sure why that would be the case?

Comment: Please add more info for the question to the question via edit not in comments.