# How do you change the shift-ctrl-e (emoji) shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

shift-ctrl-e seems to be bound to Emoji (System wide). However, this clashes with other kdb shortcuts, e.g. in Google docs.

How do I change this keyboard shortcut?

Also where in the system are the keyboard shortcuts stored (i.e. the ones that you access via the settings app)

Comment: Please mention the distro and its version.

Comment: Thank you - Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: The keyboard shortcut can be changed in ibus-setup. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039008/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-emoji-picker/1039039#1039039